# Windows Authentication - Get User/Group

Tags: php, windows, authentication

I have Windows Auth with two rules setup in IIS.  I am using this with a PHP site.  I know I can get the logged in user with $_SERVER['Remote_User'].  How can I get the group the user was in from the Authorization Rule?  I want to be able to show specific stuff on the site based on the AD group they are in.

Answer (score 0):

> the group the user was in

A user can be in several groups and those groups can be inside other groups. So, you have to anticipate, that there will be more than one group per user.

IIS doesn't send the group membership to the called php script. You need to lookup the groups yourself (e.g. using this function from the internet):

```
<?php
function get_groups($user) {
    // Active Directory server
    $ldap_host = "ad.domain";

    // Active Directory DN, base path for our querying user
    $ldap_dn = "CN=Users,DC=ad,DC=domain";

    // Active Directory user for querying
    $query_user = "jane@".$ldap_host;
    $password = "password1234!";

    // Connect to AD
    $ldap = ldap_connect($ldap_host) or die("Could not connect to LDAP");
    ldap_bind($ldap,$query_user,$password) or die("Could not bind to LDAP");

    // Search AD
    $results = ldap_search($ldap,$ldap_dn,"(samaccountname=$user)",array("memberof","primarygroupid"));
    $entries = ldap_get_entries($ldap, $results);

    // No information found, bad user
    if($entries['count'] == 0) return false;

    // Get groups and primary group token
    $output = $entries[0]['memberof'];
    $token = $entries[0]['primarygroupid'][0];

    // Remove extraneous first entry
    array_shift($output);

    // We need to look up the primary group, get list of all groups
    $results2 = ldap_search($ldap,$ldap_dn,"(objectcategory=group)",array("distinguishedname","primarygrouptoken"));
    $entries2 = ldap_get_entries($ldap, $results2);

    // Remove extraneous first entry
    array_shift($entries2);

    // Loop through and find group with a matching primary group token
    foreach($entries2 as $e) {
        if($e['primarygrouptoken'][0] == $token) {
            // Primary group found, add it to output array
            $output[] = $e['distinguishedname'][0];
            // Break loop
            break;
        }
    }

    return $output;
}
```

Source: https://samjlevy.com/php-ldap-membership/

For the function to work, you need to set the first 4 variables to the correct values (depending on your environment). Active Directory requires authentication before you can enumerate the user/group list (This is the default). So you will need some valid credentials to do the lookup.

Comment: I used to authenticate via a LDAP function...I switched to using IIS Windows Auth so I figured I wouldn't have to use LDAP to get their group.  If that's the case, I'll just got back to using LDAP for both auth and access.  Thanks

Comment: If the answer satisfies yor question, please accept it.